# Dreamhost nightmare! Deploying Rails: failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, bundler, dreamhost, gem-bundler

I've been trying to deploy my website to dreamhost for the last two weeks. I've been reading blogs created in 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011.

It seems like I fix one issue another pops up!

I've added the GEMHOME GEMPATH etc variables.

Now finally when I think I've got it working, I get this error:
   Error message:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a VPS? I wouldn't bother trying without a VPS.

I have a VPS with 450mb memory dedicated, running one production Rails 2 site with also one background job, app uses page caching a lot to save resources. I'm currently 'not' running a Rails 3 site. However, I have successfully deployed Rails 3 apps on my VPS for test purposes.

Most likely I would have to raise memory a bit to run a production Rails 3 site. Memory quickly becomes a problem.

Dreamhost will kill processes that take too much memory. When using a VPS Dreamhost will reset server that exceed dedicated memory.

Maybe you are just trying to load too much in memory? I'm not sure but anyway, without a VPS and raising memory I personally wouldn't bother trying.

Comment: right dea.I wish I'd write a blog with the heading- RAILS 3 ON DREAMHOST? DON'T BOTHER IF YOU ARE ON SHARED! After upgrading it now works! A big thank you to you sir!